# My heading names shows up over the wrong column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I flip the positions on hour and count? Please see pic

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/lisa/Desktop/data.log', names=[0, 'hour', 2, 3], sep=':', engine='python')

x_df = pd.DataFrame(x)

x_df = x_df.rename_axis('counts')

x_df=(x_df[0: 10])

x_df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use:

```
x_df.T # or x_df.transpose()
```

This will transpose the dataframe. Please see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

**Edit:**
Now i think I got what you need :)
Please try:

```
x_df.index.names = ['hour']
x_df.rename(columns={'hour': 'counts'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: If I transpose will it just transpose. My problem is that hour is above the count. As you can see, the hour 195 doesnt even exists. You can see the pic in the link https://ibb.co/buJkWU

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please see if this is better now :)